(Vue) Typescript/JS + WebSocket audio notification
I put my play-sound function in composable function. I need to play audio every time socket sends an event. But there is a problem, I can see what browser sound-play-icon appears, but there is no sound of an audio. But if I play it in setInterval, audio in setInterval and the ones played by webSocket works. I have no idea what causes that response. And I know about interaction with DOM to play something. Here is my code, if conditions are right, the only problem is audio
How do I make audio play? Cause sometimes it plays. I need reliable mechanism
I would be very thankful to someone who would tell me what`s the problem.
I have made a composable function, it correctly gets an event. I checked - audio volume is max - 1, I set currentTime to start.
Composable (gets an event correctly):
import notificationSound from '@/shared/assets/sounds/accepted_substation_notification_sound.mp3'
    
export function usePlayNotification({ conditionStatus, userSubstationId }: { conditionStatus: string, userSubstationId: number | null | undefined }) {
  const userStatus = conditionStatus
  const userSubstation = userSubstationId
  const audio = new Audio(notificationSound)

  function canPlayNotification({ status, substation_id }: { status: string, substation_id: number | null }) {
    if (substation_id && substation_id === userSubstation && status === userStatus) {
      audio.currentTime = 0
      audio.volume = 1
      audio.play()
    }
  }
  return canPlayNotification
}

main file(partly):
import { usePlayNotification } from "@/features/new-incident-notification";

const currentUserStore = useCurrentUserStore();
const router = useRouter();
const isFirstRender = ref(true);
const webSocketStore = useWebSocketsStore();
const playNotification = usePlayNotification({
  conditionStatus: INCIDENT_STATUSES.ASSIGNED_SUBSTATION,
  userSubstationId: currentUserStore.currentUser?.substation,
});

onMounted(async () => {
  webSocketStore.subscribe(
    WEBSOCKET_EVENTS.INCIDENT_STATUS_CHANGED,
    playNotification
  );
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  webSocketStore.unsubscribe(
    WEBSOCKET_EVENTS.INCIDENT_STATUS_CHANGED,
    playNotification
  );
});



The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , currently only you can debug it. It's not evident that the condition is true and audio.play() is reached. You need to log the timestamps, so this could be reproduced with a timeout or interval. I see no reasons for this to not work specifically with WS
